# Do Scheduled Tasks run automatically if they are missed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I'm running Windows Server 2003, and a scheduled task that was set to run was missed because an ms-access database window was left open over night.  When we closed the window, the task scheduler started running the task.  I found out the database window was left open over night by checking the Task Schedulers logs and noting the time that the job was last run.

I also noticed that the "Notify Me of Missed Tasks" menu item was not checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not "catch up" as it were, if it misses the event it will simply run the next time the event is scheduled to run.  You can add the option to close the task if it runs for a certain amount of time.  Usually that can help with making sure the task is forced closed. That assumes that your task isn't going to upset anything if it is ended abruptly by being forced closed by the task scheduler.

Comment: Okay I found several "stalled" tasks...I'm thinking about stopping them as they have been "stalled" for an entire day.

Comment: Also there appear to be quite a few "locked" access database files...as they have the same file name with an .ldb extension and what users are trying to run them inside.

Comment: I stopped the tasks but the lock files didn't disappear...

Comment: stopping the task would probably just force the task to stop.  if its access then the ldb file would continue to exist until cleaned up.